# MFC: Creating a class (CWnd?) with a CTreeCtrl and a CToolbar

Tags: mfc, cdialog, cwnd, cmfctoolbar

I have a `CDialog` based application that has two side-by-side `CTreeCtrl` and both trees have nearly identical `CToolbars` above them. Currently, when the dialog receives a message from one of the toolbars, it passes the message to the appropriate tree. I'd like to create a new class, probably derived from a CWnd, that contains one `CTreeCtrl` and one `CToolbar`. This new class would pass messages from its one toolbar to its one tree. It would remove a lot of redundant code (presumably) simplify ongoing development.

My question is, is `CWnd` the appropriate class for this task (to combine a `CTreeCtrl` and `CToolbar`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `CWnd` is the perfect container to encapsulate multiple controls. It was a bit of a challenge to register my class, but after that, the messaging worked great.

Comment: Make sure to set `WS_EX_CONTROL­PARENT` style for the `CWnd` so TAB navigation works as expected.